# Try two two reverse proxies in sequence in nxinx?

Tags: nginx

I want to reverse-proxy to a server through `nginx` and, based on the response (for example, a `4xx`) forward the request onto a second proxy. So when a request comes in, nxinx passes it onto the first. If the first gives a non-error response then it should return as normal. If it returns an error then nginx should send it to the second and return that response.

From a cursory reading of the documentation I don't think I can do this just through the config. I can write an nginx extension to do this, but I thought I'd ask in case it's possible without writing extra code.

Comment: I am a little unclear about the flow of traffic here.  To clarify, if the a backend server of the first reverse proxy returns a 404 code, you then want to send this response to another proxy?

Comment: Wrong. You are entirely clear about what I'm after.

Comment: I don't think what you state is possible with standard configuration. I don't think there is a way to intercept the response and conditionally re-process it. I know you asked about Nginx, but Varnish has methods to re-process requests from the backend.  See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleRestarts

Comment: Thank you. I thought not. If you give this as an answer I'll accept it if no-one else can say otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you state is possible with standard configuration. I don't think there is a way to intercept the response and conditionally re-process it.

Also, even if you write a module, latency could be an issue.  You would need to make 2 roundtrips on the backend just to send data to the client.

I know you asked about Nginx, but Varnish has methods to re-process requests from the backend. See varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleRestarts